# Why is content seen as text/html?

Tags: html, css, tomcat8

css, js, jpg, etc in Java Web App are all seen as text/html type.

for example if I put in the url:

domain.com:8080/Application/css/bootstrap.min.css

it loads as text

Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

The Java web app is fine in local, but when I upload it to the production server the problem occurs.

So in local is fine:

localhost:8080/Application/css/bootstrap.min.css

Content-Type: text/css;charset=UTF-8

Everything was fine for years until a couple of days ago.

Comment: What did you change a couple of days ago?

Comment: As far as I know I didn't change anything. The strange thing is that it all works fine in localhost and not on the production server. I tried different browsers/ computers and still get the problem. It has to be a server side problem, but I haven't touched the servers in months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the problem. Basically in my SecurityFilter.java class, which I set on my web.xml file with the  parameter, I was explicitly declaring the ContentType to text/html for all content. I have now deleted the line and everything is seen by the browser in the right MIME type.

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(...) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        ...
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that I had this line in my code for years and never caused a problem. I still have no idea what happened in the last few days that caused it to create a problem. If someone has the answer I will sleep better at night knowing the reason.

Comment: Its not a server side problem, as the problem occurs from one client/computer on the network but not on another. Both browsers accessing the same Java WebApp on the same tomcat server.